# How can I run a job yearly with anacron?

Tags: 12.04, anacron

I'd like to use anacron to run a job annually.  I see only daily, weekly, and monthly configuration for anacron.  Is there a way to run a job once per year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ofcourse and it is already there with the possible selections you have: pick 1 specific day and 1 specific month and it will run once per year. Day 1 of month 1 would be on the 1st of January.

Anacron has 2 ways of defining lines. The 2nd one is like this:

```
 @period_name delay job-identify command
```

The period_name can be set to daily, weekly, monthly, yearly or annualy. This will ensure jobs are run once a week, month or year no matter the number of days in this period.

Example

```
@yearly 0 job1 /usr/bin/execute_me
```

The 0 means no delay. job1 is an identifier and the command to execute.

Comment: How would @period_name work with anacron?  I thought it was used in crontab, which doesn't guarantee execution if the machine is off.

Comment: Here you go @JeremyStein http://linux.die.net/man/5/anacrontab or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/anacrontab.5.html ;)

Comment: Ah, so could I add a line to anacrontab like this:  `@yearly 20 cron.yearly nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.yearly` and then add my scripts to `/etc/cron.yearly`?

Comment: Do not know for sure but that last part (nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.yearly) probably needs to be 1 command (not that that is a problem since you can toss that in a script and execute the script).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work unless my computer was off for all of January:

File in `/etc/cron.monthly`:

```
#!/bin/sh
month=`date +%m`
if [ $month -eq 1 ]
then do_yearly_task
fi
```